# do_softirq execution times

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand at what times do_softirq is called

a) From interrupt return path
b) When the softirqd daemon is woken up.

Q1. What are other places which invoke it.

Q2. Does raise_softirq call do_softirq ?

Now softirq always runs in interrupt context, so softirqd daemon also runs in interrupt context ?
But softirqd is picked up by scheduler.

Q3. How does kernel do throttling of softirqs in case of high network load. How does CPU gets to process User process. Say playing a streaming video.

Answer (score 0):

A1. `do_softirq` is called from `__local_bh_enable` and `netif_rx_ni` only.

A2. Not in direct way. `raise_softirq` wakes up kernel thread `ksoftirqd` which runs `run_ksoftirqd` function, which in turn invokes `__do_softirq()` -> `__local_bh_enable()` -> `do_softirq()`.

Softirq doesn't run in interrupt context, because the purpose of softirq is to move most of interrupt handling out of interrupt context. softirqd threads run in kernel context.

A3. softirqd threads are managed by the same scheduler, so that they are equal to user threads in terms of scheduling.